# MySQL query in PHP no longer works

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I took over maintenance of this website, and I only know basic commands of **MySQL**. When WordPress updated to version 4.3.1 this query stopped working. It worked fine for months up until then.

The user inputs information into a form which is passed into the **MySQL database**, this still works. Then data is extracted from the form that was filled out, and emailed to the company. The email goes through but the fields are empty.

`'$query = "INSERT INTO ..._app (appid,$insert_keys) VALUES ('',$insert_values)";`

```
mysql_query($query)
            or die(mysql_error());

$app_query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(appid) AS appid FROM ..._app")
    or die(mysql_error());
$app_row = mysql_fetch_array($app_query);
extract($app_row);
$agent_msg = "...
    \n
    Application ID: $appid\n
    Borrower Information\n
    First Name: $fname\r
    Middle: $mname\r
    Last Name: $lname\r
```

...etc. Yes, I know this is MySQL which is deprecated, but the client is not willing to have everything rewritten at this time. It seems too coincidental that this stopped working when WordPress was updated. I'm not sure if it's fixable in the MySQL `code`.

Comment: Howdy. Are you able to obtain the query in plain text and run it in the database to separate the issue between php issue or database issue? You may see that the plain text version of the query is not what you expect and find your problem.

Comment: For me updating WordPress causing this program. Can you downgrade it anyhow .

Comment: Change your `mysql_query`  to `$wpdb->query()` or use wp's prepared statements.

Comment: Fwiw, I don't think it's the Wordpress update, but it seems plausible that the host updated PHP at the same time. You can probably downgrade that through the cpanel - although of course you should really update the code to something less vulnerable, with the proper use of prepared statements

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, please post it.

Comment: imho, if the client is unwilling to have the code rewritten you should deny any support on the website; let them know it has been deprecated because of loopholes and that you aren't willing to deliver subpar hacks and workarounds.

Comment: what @Nerdwood says: please post any error messages you get. Else it's just poking in the dark.

Comment: There are no error messages. That's why I'm so perplexed!

Comment: I wish I could downgrade WordPress. The client's previous developer did not put a backup utility on the site and did not have a backup service with their hosting provider.

Comment: This is a small portion of several thousand lines of code. The client is not willing to pay to have it all rewritten in another language.

Comment: PHP is only version 5.3, and since MySQL was deprecated as of version 5.5, I would think that PHP is not the problem.

Comment: I'm at a beginner level with MySQL, so I have not tried to run it in plain text in the database. I don't know how exactly to do that, but I will figure it out and give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

you should check all your form field name and debug with print_r($_REQUEST) and see, it will return all the field or not. If yes, than you can also try below WP function:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 'table name', array( 'field 1' => $_REQUEST['field 1'], 'field 2' => $_REQUEST['field 2']));
```

Comment: Can I intermix the WP functions written here within the MySQL code in the same document?